# Кол-во колонок в таблице

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Как посчитать кол-во колонок в таблице с помощью php?

Comment: База данных MySQL?

Comment: @Y.Ghorbani , да

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка подключения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1")) {

    /* определяем количество стобцов в результирующей таблице */
    $field_cnt = $result->field_count;

    printf("Результат содержит %d полей.\n", $field_cnt);

    /* закрываем результирующий набор */
    $result->close();
}

/* закрываем подключение */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name
```

Дока: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_name='Имя таблицы';
```